# Help replicating this red pattern and glow effect (speed lines) in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, gradient, blur

Firstly thanks for reading and any help offered!

I need to recreate the red pattern from this image in illustrator. I've tried a couple of different methods but the best I can come up with is to manually draw the lines and apply an outline blue but this doesn't seem quite right.

Any tips or tricks anyone could recommend?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there are many ways one could go about this. One method is to use narrow ellipses filled with a gradient.  These are all the same ellipse copied and pasted multiple times, some narrower and some wider, and some I edited by moving the red stop so it comes further up the ellipse. Everything is then cropped by using a clipping mask over a black filled rectangle grouped with the ellipses.

Example

[image]

Note: the black stop in the gradient is set to a 100% M,Y, and K. and so too is the fill of the rectangle used as the background,  otherwise the gradient woudn't look right against the background. The gradients could be further tweaked so that there is more bright red at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be to use strokes with *profiles** assigned and a **Blend**.

Simply create a blend between a few paths with stroke profiles. You can then duplicate the blend object and move the paths around to create different variations.

[image]